# No Samsung SSD found

Tags: linux

when I use this command

```
samsung_magician_dc-v1.0_rtm_p2/64bin $ sudo ./magician  -L
```

it tells me "No samsung SSD found".What shall I do?

I run ubuntu 14.04 and i got this on using sudo ./magician -l

Comment: we need more info...

Comment: Do you have a Samsung SSD? Which model and what precisely is it connected to?

Comment: Its a samsung evo 850 and connected to an Asus H97 architecture.I parttioned it to /boot,/, etc and only the boot up is associated with the ssd(128gb).use it only for installing and opening up apps.have a 1tb HDD for the other stuff

Comment: Samsung(R) SSD Magician DC Version 1.0
Copyright (c) 2014 Samsung Corporation
================================================================================================
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Disk   | Model   | Serial  | Firmware  | Capacity | Drive  | Total Bytes |
| Number |         | Number  |           |          | Health | Written     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
No Samsung SSD found!

Comment: this is the details from fdisk -l  Disk /dev/sdb: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbe2e92eb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1   234441647   117220823+  ee  GPT

Comment: is there any way?

Answer (score 5):

For reasons that are not clear to me, Samsung have removed the Linux versions of Magician for "consumer" SSDs.  However, it seems that the most recent version can still be accessed via the wonderful `archive.org` [1].  I was able to use this just now to upgrade the firmware on my 840 EVO 1TB -- the user manual says it supports the 850 drives too. [2]

[1] https://web.archive.org/web/20160304055322/http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/server_downloads.html

[2] https://web.archive.org/web/20160316165224/http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/downloads/software/Samsung_Magician_DC_v10_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: You're a hero!  For those interested, this version of magician also supports older Samsung enterprise SSD's, such as the 845DC (PRO/EVO) series.  Newer versions (even the "enterprise" versions) do not.  Given those SSDs are still well within their 5 years warranty, it's really mysterious as to why Samsung has decided to "unsupport" them from current tools.  I can only guess: entropy, given the general state of their SSD support site and documentation

Comment: This helped with secure erasing my PM853T 960GB too. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It seems EVO 850 is not supportted. My one also gets blank list:

```
# ./magician -L
================================================================================================
Samsung(R) SSD Magician DC Version 1.0
Copyright (c) 2014 Samsung Corporation
================================================================================================
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Disk   | Model   | Serial  | Firmware  | Capacity | Drive  | Total Bytes |
| Number |         | Number  |           |          | Health | Written     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
No Samsung SSD found!
#

# hdparm -i /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

 Model=Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB, FwRev=EMT01B6Q, SerialNo=S21GNXAG807106V
 Config={ Fixed }
 RawCHS=16383/16/63, TrkSize=0, SectSize=0, ECCbytes=0
 BuffType=unknown, BuffSize=unknown, MaxMultSect=1, MultSect=1
 CurCHS=16383/16/63, CurSects=16514064, LBA=yes, LBAsects=976773168
 IORDY=on/off, tPIO={min:120,w/IORDY:120}, tDMA={min:120,rec:120}
 PIO modes:  pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
 DMA modes:  mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 
 UDMA modes: udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
 AdvancedPM=no WriteCache=enabled
 Drive conforms to: unknown:  ATA/ATAPI-2,3,4,5,6,7

 * signifies the current active mode

#
```

From searching, I found there were some bad reputations on Samsung SSDs with Linux:
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fstrim/+bug/1449005
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ide/59791

Better try to avoid updating the firmware if it is not really needed there.

Comment: I find it hard to believe Samsung would not support one of its main products in their own command-line utility. I also have a 850 EVO and the exact same problem as the OP (and yourself, as it seems). My `hdparm` output is also identical to yours. Thanks for the bug links! :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need Samsung Magician in Ubuntu 14.04. TRIM support is enabled automatically by default for Samsung SSDs in Ubuntu 14.04. You also don't need to update the SSD's firmware. Your Samsung SSD should be detected in the *Disks* disk utility in Ubuntu 14.04, and function properly without any additional maintenance being required.

Try using your Samsung SSD for a while without doing any additional maintenance on it, and then comment if any problem occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately **EVO 850** is not supported in Samsung SSD Magician DC 1.0, you can find this information in the [official documentation](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/downloads/software/Samsung_Magician_DC_v10_User_Guide.pdf).